# Is it possible to hide nummeric data in Eddystone EID

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

My question is more theoretical to enhance my Android application functionalities - can I hide somehow nummeric data, like max int 9999 in Eddystone EID. For security reasons i'd like to go with EID instead of UID, but also need for sending some basic information which before were put in Instance. Offline EID resolver (in application) would translate the information and tells if beacon is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

An Eddystone-EID resolver implementation's should be good enough to handle beacon's evaluation just checking the EID the beacon is sending.

However, if you need data associated with the beacons for another purpose, the answer is yes. If your resolver is based on the Google's and have something similar to their Attachments concept, you will be able to associate arbitrary data to the beacon after its registration.

See https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/attachments for more info about Attachments.

See https://developers.google.com/beacons/eddystone-eid for more info about Eddystone-EID Attachments.